# How to fetch profile from server

Tags: iphone, json, xcode, parse-platform, authentication

I create a Sign up and sign in form. and i want user id from getting personal data. It starts with a login screen with personal email and password fields after authentication it moves to profile page and show respective profile. like this user image , name, email id, address. My storyboard Flow is Sign up> Login> View Profile.

values stored in server database and login properly. but can't fetch personal details.

I think i am not explaining properly please try to understand and help me.

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: you are probably best off choosing an open source CMS that will handle security

Comment: @rohit jindal I tried many times but any time open same profile. I want particular user login and show own profile. please help me.